# How can I add expressive translation to KnockoutJS via i18n?

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

In my KnockoutJS files I have:

```
<a href="/policies/shipping-policy" target="_blank" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Policy'"></a>
```

What I want to do is translate this block:

```
<span>
By clicking submit order you agree to our <a href="/policies/terms-and-conditions/" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>
and to receive promotional emails from the Site You can
subsequently opt out of receiving such
promotional e-mails by clicking on the link at the bottom of any promotional email</span>
```

I have tried to do this:

```
<span data-bind="i18n: 'By clicking submit order you agree to our <a href="/policies/terms-and-conditions/" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a> and to receive promotional emails from the Site You can subsequently opt out of receiving such promotional e-mails by clicking on the link at the bottom of any promotional email'"></span>
```

But it does not work - I want to be able to add the href and other possible information inside that bind.

Comment: What i18n binding handler do you use?

Comment: Magento 2 - not sure

Comment: That does not answer the question. `i18n` is not a built-in binding handler with knockout so the first thing to do would be to find out which custom binding handler is being used here and how it works, I would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once created an internationalization custom binding that worked like so:

1. Put data-bind on surrounding element:

   ```
   <div data-bind="i18n">
     The quick brown <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox">fox</a> jumps over the lazy dog.
   </div>
   ```
2. Replace all of the data-bound element's children with a generic placeholder, e.g.: `$1`, `$2`, etc.. Store the elements you've replaced.

   **Parent**:

   ```
   <div data-bind="i18n">
     The quick brown $1 jumps over the lazy dog.
   </div>
   ```

   **Children**:

   `<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox">fox</a>`
3. Use your translation library to replace the string in the parent. Something like:

   ```
   parentElement.innerText = translate(parentElement.innerText);
   ```
4. Replace your placeholders with the cached elements, and return

   Go from (example in Dutch):

   ```
   <div data-bind="i18n">
     De snelle bruine $1 springt over de luie hond.
   </div>
   ```

   To:

   ```
   <div data-bind="i18n">
     De snelle bruine <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox">fox</a> springt over de luie hond.
   </div>
   ```
5. Now, if you also want to translate *fox* (which, of course, you do), you put an `i18n` binding on there as well. Your translation dictionary would have to contain:

   ```
    var dutch = {
      "The quick brown $1 jumps over the lazy dog.": 
        "De snelle bruine $1 springt over de luie hond.",
      "fox": 
        "vos"
    }
   ```

To create a solid, bug free implementation you'll need to do some extra work... But it might work out for you.

An example to illustrate: (Note that this is not optimized for performance and not bug free or feature complete.. (e.g.: replacing the `$1` strings doesn't respect reorders))

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.i18n = {
  init: function(element) {
    var ogChildren = Array.from(element.children)
      .map(function replaceAndReturn(c, i) {
        return element.replaceChild(PlaceHolder(i), c);
      });

    var translation = translate(element.innerText);
    if (!translation) return;
    
    ogChildren.forEach(function(_, i) {
      translation = translation.replace("$" + i, HTMLPlaceHolder(i).outerHTML);
    });

    element.innerHTML = translation; // Parses the span strings to elements

    Array.from(element.querySelectorAll("span[data-tindex]"))
      .forEach(function(c, i) {
        element.replaceChild(ogChildren[i], c); // Puts back in og children
      });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({});

function PlaceHolder(i) {
  return document.createTextNode("$" + i);
}

function HTMLPlaceHolder(tIndex) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("data-tindex", tIndex);
  return span;
}

function translate(key) {
  var dutch = {
    "The quick brown $0 jumps over the lazy dog.": 
      "De snelle bruine $0 springt over de luie hond.",
    "fox":
      "vos"
  };

  return dutch[key];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="i18n">
  The quick brown <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox">fox</a> jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>

<div data-bind="i18n">
  The quick brown <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox" data-bind="i18n">fox</a> jumps over the lazy dog.
</div>
```